# How to get card value after clicking in loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, web, frontend

I have this script for create cards based on list using for loop:

```
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var mokData = [
            { category: "Material", id: '1', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
            { category: "Material", id: '2', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
            { category: "Tool", id: '3', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
            { category: "Tool", id: '4', name: 'Brakedown of line' },
            { category: "Tool", id: '5', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
            { category: "Tool", id: '6', name: 'Brakedown of line' },
            { category: "Tool", id: '7', name: 'Brakedown of machine' },
            { category: "Tool", id: '8', name: 'Brakedown of line' }
        ];
        $.each(mokData, function (i) {
            var templateString = '<article class="card"><h2>' + mokData[i].category + '</h2><p>' + mokData[i].name + '</p><p>' + mokData[i].id + '</p><button id="tes">Start</button></article>';
            $('#test12').append(templateString);
        })

        $("#test12 button").on("click", function () {
            alert();
        });

    });
</script>
```

Now I need to get the value when the button clicked

Comment: which value do you need to get i.e : `mokData[i].name` ?

Comment: @Swati Yes for ex

Comment: Simply use : `$(this).closest(".card").find("p:eq(0)").text()` then for `id` use `1` instead of `0` . Also , you can assign some class to your `p` tag then inside `.find()` get there value using that class name for eg : `...find(".classname")`.

Answer (score 0):

In this line:

```
$('#test12').append(templateString);
```

JQuery is returning an element which you can directly add an event listener to. You can do something like this:

```
const element = $('#test12').append(templateString);
const thisData = mokData[i];
$(element).click(function() {
    console.log(thisData); //mock data related to the item you've just clicked
});
```

In the method above, you don't need to attach any additional data to the DOM, you can just reference what you already have access to.

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you can attach a click handler to all `button` elements and use the reference to the clicked element, available through the Event object passed to the handler function, to retrieve the content from the HTML related to that button. Try this:

```js
jQuery($ => {
  var mokData = [{category:"Material",id:'1',name:'Brakedown of machine'},{category:"Material",id:'2',name:'Brakedown of machine'},{category:"Tool",id:'3',name:'Brakedown of machine'},{category:"Tool",id:'4',name:'Brakedown of line'},{category:"Tool",id:'5',name:'Brakedown of machine'},{category:"Tool",id:'6',name:'Brakedown of line'},{category:"Tool",id:'7',name:'Brakedown of machine'},{category:"Tool",id:'8',name:'Brakedown of line'}]
  
  // create HTML from array of objects
  let html = mokData.map(o => `<article class="card"><h2>${o.category}</h2><p>${o.name}</p><p>${o.id}</p><button>Start</button></article>`);
  $('#test12').append(html);

  // handle button click and retrieve nearest id
  $("#test12 button").on("click", e => {
    let $btn =  $(e.target);
    let id = $btn.closest('.card').find('p:eq(1)').text();
    console.log(id);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="test12"></div>
```

Note that I removed `id="tes"` from the button in the HTML you create as that will result in repeated `id` values which is invalid - they *must* be unique within the DOM.